# How to serialize a data structure which is instance of Data?

Tags: haskell, generics, serialization

I want to serialize a data structure which is partially defined by my own, and partially is using data structures that come from an external library (which is an instance of Data). I wanted to do the serialization without having to define how the serialization process should work, or in other words, in a rather automatic way.

I've been trying several alternatives I've found by googling/asking. None of them was successful. Library ([genericserialize](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/genericserialize)) seemed what I was looking for. Unfortunately, it does not work even for simple cases (like (True, False)). It is probably outdated or/and incomplete. Binary serialization requires that the external data structure derives Binary (which it does not). With [Cereal](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal) similar problems arise. Of course, it is Read/Show, but again, the external data structure does not derive Read, so it neither can be used.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something. I thought when I first faced this problem it would be easier. In other languages, like Erlang for instance, this is done in a very simple way.

Do you know libraries/techniques or whatever to make this process as simple as possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Data.Binary`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-0.8.4.0/docs/Data-Binary.html).

Derive `Generic` for all data types involved. This will require the [`-XDeriveGeneric`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#ghc-flag--XDeriveGeneric) pragma. If the data types from the external libraries you are using don't do this, you might have to have a module of [orphan instances](https://wiki.haskell.org/Orphan_instance) and use [`-XStandaloneDeriving`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#stand-alone-deriving-declarations).

Once that is done, you can use the fact that the `Binary` class already has support for deriving from `Generic`. You'll need to enable [`-XDeriveAnyclass`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#ghc-flag--XDeriveAnyClass) and then you can add `Binary` instances for all data types involved (you might again have to have standalone instances for types from the external library).

## EDIT

The [OP added a gist](https://gist.github.com/tamarit/4673818ba86d35b9a73875fe2e222c75). Then, to get this to compile, we need to add the following language pragmas:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable,
             DeriveAnyClass,
             DeriveGeneric,
             StandaloneDeriving #-}
```

And the following imports:

```
import Language.C.Syntax.AST
import Language.C.Data.Position
import Language.C.Data.Node
import Language.C.Data.Name
import Language.C.Data.Ident
import Language.C.Syntax.Constants

import Data.Data
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Binary
```

From the OPs gist:

```
type CTypeSpecAnn = CTypeSpecifier NodeAnn 
type CDeclAnn = CDeclaration NodeAnn
type CDeclSpecAnn = CDeclarationSpecifier NodeAnn
type CDeclrAnn = CDeclarator NodeAnn
type CStatAnn = CStatement NodeAnn
type CExtDeclAnn = CExternalDeclaration NodeAnn
type CExprAnn = CExpression NodeAnn
type CBlockItemAnn = CCompoundBlockItem NodeAnn
type CTranslUnitAnn = CTranslationUnit NodeAnn

data TransState = 
    TransState 
    {
        free_node_id :: Int,
        freeVar :: Int,
        includes :: [String],
        fun_defs :: [(String, (CTypeSpecAnn, [CDeclAnn], ([CDeclSpecAnn], CDeclrAnn, [CDeclAnn], NodeAnn)), CStatAnn)],
        no_fun_defs :: [CExtDeclAnn],
        last_changed :: String,
        previous_changes :: ([(String, ((String,CStatAnn,CStatAnn), TransState, [(String, CStatAnn)]))], [(String, ((String,CExprAnn,CExprAnn), TransState, [(String, CStatAnn)]))]),
        applied_rules :: [String],
        applicable_rules :: Set String,
        trans_with_anns :: Bool
    }
    deriving (Show, Data, Typeable)

type NodeAnn = Annotation NodeInfo NodeProperties
data Annotation nI nP = Ann nI nP
    deriving (Show, Data, Typeable, Eq)

data NodeProperties = 
    NodeProperties
    { 
        _hasSideEffects :: PropertyInfo Bool,
        _readIn ::  PropertyInfo [String],
        _writeIn ::  PropertyInfo [String],
        _localSymbols :: PropertyInfo [String],
        _rangeInfo :: PropertyInfo [String],
        _isCanonical :: PropertyInfo Bool,
        _isPerfectNest :: PropertyInfo Bool,
        _hasLoops :: PropertyInfo Bool,
        _hasFunctionCalls :: PropertyInfo Bool,
        _hasControlFlowModifiers :: PropertyInfo Bool,
        _scalarDependences :: PropertyInfo [String],
        _polcaPragmas :: PropertyInfo [[String]],
        _allPragmas :: PropertyInfo [String]
    } 
    deriving (Show, Data, Typeable, Eq)

data PropertyInfo a = 
    PropertyInfo
    { 
        _pragmaType :: PragmaType,
        _definedBy  :: DefinerType,
        _value :: Maybe a
    } 
    deriving (Show, Data, Typeable, Eq)

makeLenses ''NodeProperties
makeLenses ''PropertyInfo
```

Since OP never defines `PragmaType` and `DefinerType`, I'm assuming they are `()`.

```
type PragmaType = ()
type DefinerType = ()
```

Then we have a ton of `deriving instance` (we have to recursively find all type dependencies and add `Generic` and `Binary` to them).

```
deriving instance Generic (CDeclaration a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CDeclaration a)
deriving instance Generic (CTypeSpecifier a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CTypeSpecifier a)
deriving instance Generic (CDeclarationSpecifier a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CDeclarationSpecifier a)
deriving instance Generic (CDeclarator a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CDeclarator a)
deriving instance Generic (CStatement a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CStatement a)
deriving instance Generic (CExternalDeclaration a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CExternalDeclaration a)
deriving instance Generic (CExpression a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CExpression a)
deriving instance Generic (CCompoundBlockItem a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CCompoundBlockItem a)
deriving instance Generic (CTranslationUnit a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CTranslationUnit a)
deriving instance Generic (CInitializer a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CInitializer a)
deriving instance Generic (CStructureUnion a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CStructureUnion a)
deriving instance Generic (CTypeQualifier a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CTypeQualifier a)
deriving instance Generic (CStringLiteral a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CStringLiteral a)
deriving instance Generic (CAttribute a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CAttribute a)
deriving instance Generic (CPartDesignator a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CPartDesignator a)
deriving instance Generic (CFunctionDef a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CFunctionDef a)
deriving instance Generic (CAssemblyStatement a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CAssemblyStatement a)
deriving instance Generic (CAssemblyOperand a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CAssemblyOperand a)
deriving instance Generic (CConstant a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CConstant a)
deriving instance Generic (CEnumeration a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CEnumeration a)
deriving instance Generic (CStorageSpecifier a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CStorageSpecifier a)
deriving instance Generic (CDerivedDeclarator a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CDerivedDeclarator a)
deriving instance Generic (CBuiltinThing a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CBuiltinThing a)
deriving instance Generic (CArraySize a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (CArraySize a)
deriving instance Generic (Flags a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (Flags a)
deriving instance Generic NodeInfo
deriving instance Binary NodeInfo
deriving instance Generic Name
deriving instance Binary Name
deriving instance Generic Ident
deriving instance Binary Ident
deriving instance Generic CString
deriving instance Binary CString
deriving instance Generic CStructTag
deriving instance Binary CStructTag
deriving instance Generic CFloat
deriving instance Binary CFloat
deriving instance Generic CChar
deriving instance Binary CChar
deriving instance Generic CUnaryOp
deriving instance Binary CUnaryOp
deriving instance Generic CBinaryOp
deriving instance Binary CBinaryOp
deriving instance Generic CInteger
deriving instance Binary CInteger
deriving instance Generic CAssignOp
deriving instance Binary CAssignOp
deriving instance Generic CIntFlag
deriving instance Binary CIntFlag
deriving instance Generic CIntRepr
deriving instance Binary CIntRepr

deriving instance Binary TransState
deriving instance Generic TransState
deriving instance Generic (Annotation a b)
deriving instance (Binary a, Binary b) => Binary (Annotation a b)
deriving instance Generic NodeProperties
deriving instance Binary NodeProperties
deriving instance Generic (PropertyInfo a)
deriving instance Binary a => Binary (PropertyInfo a)
```

As a side note, the second half of those instances could be declared in the data declaration of the types themselves (since those are declared in the current file). The one sticking point is that we still don't have a `Binary` instance for `Position`. We can't derive it automatically since its data constructors haven't been exported. However, nothing is stopping us from writing a manual `Binary` instance.

```
instance Binary Position where
    put p | isNoPos p = putWord8 0 
          | isBuiltinPos p = putWord8 1
          | isInternalPos p = putWord8 2
          | isSourcePos p = putWord8 3 >> put (posOffset p) >> put (posFile p) >> put (posRow p) >> put (posColumn p)

    get = do
        marker <- getWord8
        case marker of
            0 -> return nopos
            1 -> return builtinPos
            2 -> return internalPos
            3 -> position <$> get <*> get <*> get <*> get
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I've tried to derive Generic, but I'm getting the following error:

    Expected kind ‘(* -> *) -> GHC.Prim.Constraint’,
      but ‘Generic’ has kind ‘(* -> *) -> *’
    In the data declaration for ‘Trans’`

Comment: What does the data definition for `Trans` look like by the way?

Comment: @SalvadorTamarit Actually, even a link to library documentation would be helpful...

Comment: TrasState: https://gist.github.com/tamarit/4673818ba86d35b9a73875fe2e222c75
Library:
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/language-c

Comment: What was the original language c data type you were trying to derive? I can't seem to find where `TransState` is defined as it isn't publicly exposed.

Comment: I've added more code to the gist that I think are needed to understand the type. `TranState`is a type defined in 'Language.C`.

Comment: @SalvadorTamarit I've done part of the work for you. Next time, please try to add more information in your post, or a minimal example to debug - otherwise it won't be too useful to the next person who stumbles onto this question from Google. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Alec. I'm still having and error when compiling which is similar to the one above:
`The first argument of ‘Generic’ should have kind ‘*’,
      but ‘Binary a’ has kind ‘GHC.Prim.Constraint’
    In the stand-alone deriving instance for
      ‘Binary a => Generic (Binary a)’`

Comment: Oops! There was a typo in the very last line. :) My copy-pasting go the better of me.

Comment: Perfect @Alec. Thanks!
I've added similar instances for almost all the types in the world ;) 
But there are one that I don't know if it's possible to be derived. It is Position.

    `Can't make a derived instance of ‘GHCG.Generic Position’:
      The data constructors of ‘Position’ are not all in scope
        so you cannot derive an instance for it
    In the stand-alone deriving instance for ‘GHCG.Generic Position’`

I want/need to work with the library as it is, so change it and recompile is not an alternative. I wonder if this solution has found a unbridgeable pitfall :P

Comment: @SalvadorTamarit Let me know if this works, and please accept the answer. :)

Comment: Yes!! It works. :) Thank you very much @Alec. I wouldn't do it without your help.